# Monotouch: How to capture the "cancel" button when sending email?

Tags: xamarin.ios, sendmail

I am trying to capture the "cancel" event when sending mail, so I can return to the previous view.  This is my code (http://monobin.com/__db8fa53f).  Tapping on the Cancel button, rather than the Send button, does nothing.  What do I need to add to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what "AppDelegate.SetView(3);" does but if the result is "MFMailComposeResult.Cancelled", you are not dismissing the mail controller. It is only being dismissed if the result is "MFMailComposeResult.Sent".

Comment: I see the problem... I have this in the "finished" method... how do I capture the "cancel" button on the SendMail modal view?

Comment: Your code is almost correct. You need two more things: 1. Dismiss the mail controller when the result is MFMailComposeResult.Cancelled. Right now you just call "AppDelegate.SetView(3)" without dismissing the controller. 2. Declare your controller outside of your method because it might be collected earlier and your finished method never get called.